# Synchronize file mask in WinSCP - merge file filter with subdirectories exclusion

Tags: windows, date, ftp, winscp

I am writing a script to synchronize two folders. I pick images from local folder and synchronize them on FTP.

I have to apply THREE filters:

1. only image files (IT WORKS: `*.jpg; *.png...`)
2. only newer files (IT WORKS: `*.png>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%`)
3. I don't want to copy folders (not working)

The code I am using works but it copies the subfolders too. On internet they say I have to use `"|*/"` to skip subfolders. But if I use this in my filemask, it copies EVERYTHING, ignoring my other filters.

This is the code I use:

Here I connect to SFTP server using a password

```
open sftp://USERNAME:PASSWORD@myFTP.com -hostkey="ssh-rsa 4096 JvxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxVx8/5VSw="
option batch
option transfer binary
```

Here I synchronize:

```
synchronize remote -filemask="*.png>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%; *.jpeg>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%; *.jpg>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%;" H:\MyImageFolder /test/DestinationFolder/ -nopreservetime
```

I tried this:

```
synchronize remote -filemask="*.png>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%; *.jpeg>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%; *.jpg>=%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%; "|*/" " H:\MyImageFolder /test/DestinationFolder/ -nopreservetime
```

But it doesn't work or it tells me that filemask has a wrong number of parameters.

How can I use my image filter (based on extension and date) and exclude subfolders from synchronization?

I found other overflow questions but no one matching my specific problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `%2019-04-10#yyyy-mm-dd%` is wrong, it should be just `2019-04-10`.
2. Your already have double-quotes around your file mask, so remove those from `"|*/"`.

See the documentation for [WinSCP file masks](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/file_mask).

---

This should do, what you want:

```
-filemask="*.png>=2019-04-10; *.jpeg>=2019-04-10; *.jpg>=2019-04-10 | */"
```